# JOOQ how to add column with default value into an existing table

Tags: java, sql, jooq

The below DSL can add new column with nullable to existing table, but i don't know how to add a default value in this DSL.

```
DSL.using(dialect).alterTable(table("tableName"))
                    .add(field(name("newColName"),VARCHAR(32).nullable(false)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way as `nullable()`, directly on the type. Use

```java
VARCHAR(32).nullable(false).default_("abc")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But the generated sql under sqlserver has a tripe quote around the default value: `alter table [TABLE] add [C2] varchar(32) null default '''ABCD'''` which cause the default value became `ABCD` instead of ABCD. How can i change this behavior to not use tripe quote.

Comment: @merlin: How did you execute that query?

Comment: i use getSQL() to get the sql string and pass it to jdbc's `Statement.executeUpdate`

Comment: @merlin: I can't reproduce this. Best ask a new question with a complete reproducer...

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time lukas. This is caused by a single quote in existing string. There is nothing to do with jooq. Thanks again for your fast response.

Comment: How do you add a new column with default, etc., but only if it doesn't already exist? It seems that setting defaults etc. can be done only on existing columns.

Comment: @AdamHošek: Can you open a new question here on Stack Overflow, with details?